# Scrolling to latest rendered component

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

how can I pass ref to latest rendered component in this situation so page will scroll to him after its render? The example below obviosuly doesn't work but I dont have any idea how to do it.

Edit: Added ShortenedLink component according to comments.

```
const ref = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
   ref.current.scrollIntoView();
}, [linkArr]);

return(
    <LinkShortenerContainer >
        <LinkShortener
          setLinkArr={setLinkArr}
        />
        <AnimatePresence>
          {linkArr.map((item) => {
            return (
              <ShortenedLink
                ref={ref}
                setLinkArr={setLinkArr}
                key={item.id}
                id={item.id}
                long={item.long}
                short={item.short}
              />
            );
          })}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </LinkShortenerContainer>
)

export default function ShortenedLink({ long, short, id, setLinkArr }) {
  const [isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(short);
    setIsCopied(true);
  };
  const removeLink = () => {
    setLinkArr((prev) =>
      prev.filter((item) => {
        return item.id !== id;
      })
    );
  };
  return (
    <ShortenedLinkContainer
      as={motion.div}
      initial={{ x: -1500, opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
      exit={{ x: 1500, opacity: 0 }}
    >
      <LinkToShorten>{long}</LinkToShorten>
      <ReadyLink>{short}</ReadyLink>
      <Button
        size={"medium"}
        text={isCopied ? "Copied !" : "Copy !"}
        onClick={() => handleClick()}
      ></Button>
      <IconContainer>
        <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => removeLink()} icon={faX} size={"sm"} />
      </IconContainer>
    </ShortenedLinkContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide the <ShortenedLink compoment.

Comment: Added ShortenedLink component to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same requirement when writing my chat app: rolling to the latest message.
My way is to put an empty `div` after all messages. then all I need is to scroll to that `div` instead of putting `ref` in every newly created message.